# Downvoting tóxico. ¿Qué se puede hacer al respecto?

Tags: discusión

[Mi última pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/596738/3436) habla por sí sola, pero procederé a intentar resumirlo.

Tengo una duda complicada sobre un código de ejemplo de X artículo que trato de entender. Procedo a desarrollar la pregunta incluyendo todos los detalles pertinentes posibles. Me aseguro de adaptar mi código a los lectores con la filosofía de "ejemplo mínimo reproducible"... **me paso horas revisando la pregunta, mejorándola una y otra vez** esperando el más mínimo feedback...

...cuando por fin obtengo interacción, es un voto negativo y ni se digna a explicarse... al final **respondí mi propia pregunta, asunto resuelto**. Gracias por el "hate" downvoter desconocido

No me parece ni medio normal, pero bueno. **Para una pregunta que se me ocurre hacer**, de varias respuestas que habré dado ya...

Este sitio tiene un nivel de toxicidad comparable al del StackOverflow original. ¿Qué podemos hacer al respecto?

Más contexto aquí, [en este hilo de MetaStackExchange English](https://meta-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

---

Esta pregunta no busca respuesta al comportamiento del voto negativo impulsivo, sino a la búsqueda de formas de evitar el impacto de los votos negativos impulsivos, así como posibles contramedidas que pudieran (o no) implementarse. No me sorprendería que, en muchos casos, una intervención de "cola de revisión" impulsiva y prematura generase votos negativos en cascada (como por ejemplo "prejuzgar que la pregunta demuestra poco esfuerzo de investigación" por decir un ejemplo) tan sólo "porque la mayoría del código de la pregunta coincide con un ejemplo externo". **Especialmente en las preguntas con cero actividad**. En este sentido, se dan casos de "usuarios con privilegios de moderación" que intervienen con un copy-pasta de "deberías ver este [help center howto] para hacer una pregunta" cuando ese ejemplo mínimo ejecutable **ya estaba, de hecho, en la pregunta.** (a mí me ha pasado). Lo cual da la impresión por parte del moderador de turno de "haberse mirado la pregunta por encima 5 segundos" ( o menos ) y **ya creer saber lo que le falta a la pregunta**. Este ejemplo es del StackOverflow original, pero bien los ejemplos resultan extrapolables.

**Esto no va sólamente de la pregunta que ejemplifica el tema en el enlace del primer párrafo.** (que ya no viene al caso). Va del tema en general. Estos "votos negativos impulsivos" como yo los llamo, minan la moral de quienes se esfuerzan por detallar el contexto de una pregunta como pueden. Talvez (por decir algo) se podría "poner un popup que desaconseje el voto impulsivo" en preguntas con interacción 0, o menos de 20 views... por decir algo...

Comment: ¿Por qué un voto en contra sería "tóxico" o de "hater"?

Comment: Habiendo cumplido todos los requisitos para hacer una buena pregunta? Pues a saber... que alguien me lo explique. Desde luego un Downvote tras mostrar todo ese esfuerzo sin ni siquiera dar un porqué es, como mínimo, **una falta de respeto**

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué votan negativo sin dar ninguna explicación al respecto?](/q/955)

Comment: Tu pregunta original peca por exceso: es demasiado larga. Tenía intenciones de examinarla, pero al rato me canse. Seguro que encontraba el problema en un santiamen, pero se me agota el entusiasmo a medio camino. (No la vote).

Comment: Bueno, como sea. Si StackOverflow en Español sigue por este camino, que espere sentado a que gente como yo vaya por ahí buscando preguntas que responder. Eventualmente la calidad del sitio se verá resentida por la impasibilidad de los moderadores, como ya pasó en el StackOverflow original.

Comment: Leí tu pregunta, en lo personal no me parece que merece un voto negativo. Obviamente hay quien pensó que si, y bueno, aunque sería deseable que dejara un comentario, tampoco es obligatorio. Probablemente se trate de un _hater_, y esos no podemos impedir que existan. En mi caso, aparecen votos negativos de pronto en mis respuestas o preguntas y, aunque no veo la razón, al final simplemente los ignoro. A veces no puedo evitar sentir que es injusto, pero así opera el mundo, no solo StackOverflow.

Comment: @jachguate Agradezco tu comprensión. Soy consciente de que el comportamiento es legal, pero no por eso deja de ser incívico. Agradezco tu empatía

Comment: @Sebas, si notas un patrón de votos negativos, puedes reportarlo a un moderador y obtener ayuda. Es algo que nunca he hecho, supongo que debe haber un mínimo para considerarlo una agresión directa. 10 o 20 en un solo día, quizás, no sabría decir cuantos. Mi consejo es que no te fijes tanto en ellos y que tu motivación no dependa de eso. En lo personal yo siento que la reputación en SOes es mucho más difícil de ganar que en SO, y sin embargo, aquí estoy, porque me motiva más ayudar a la gente de habla hispana.

Comment: @jachguate es bueno saberlo, pero no recurriré a tal mecanismo de momento. Mis preguntas nunca llegan a despegar en visualizaciones a causa de haters y moderadores tóxicos (me refiero en concreto a un caso aún peor que este hace meses en StackOverflow English). Mi motivación para postear nada en la plataforma de StackExchange en consecuencia está muriendo. Tal es la ansiedad que me genera este tema que *ya ni puedo concentrarme en mi Código*... para qué voy a perder tiempo discutiendo por algo que ni soluciona el problema ni parece tener solución? La próxima vez pregunto por Discord u otra...

Comment: Por si interesa ver a qué caso peor que éste me estoy refiriendo de StackOverflow English (meses después aún estoy **muy cabreado**) ésta es [mi respuesta al Meta](https://meta-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming/425227?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp#425227) "¿Por qué StackOverflow se siente tan poco acogedor?" Traducida al español para los no-entendidos (con traducción peor que mediocre como cabía esperar de Google Translate, pero aún así comprensible)

Comment: Entiendo tu queja. No voy a negar que tu pregunta es algo larga. Los excesos siempre son malos y es importante mantener el interes del lector. Pero si, los votos, que resultan en realidad ser formas de indicar la calidad de la pregunta y no ataques a la persona, deberían requerir explicación, al igual que los likes de cualquier red social. Te doy la razon, por motivos diferentes, que so tiene un grave problema de moderación, pero no es toxico.

Comment: Te voto positivo para que los problemas de moderación del sitio sean escuchados.

Comment: @CandidMoe entonces hay que comerse el posible voto negativo injusto de manera sumiza y callada? Y llenar de negativos a cualquiera que se queje y defienda de la deficiente moderación?

Comment: También vote para cerrar esta pregunta, por duplicada.

Comment: @Candid Moe No habrá próxima publicación. Revisa el hilo de Meta StackOverflow English (traducido al español por si no sabes inglés) para averiguar por qué. Estoy hasta los cojones de repetir las mismas cosas mil veces. Hala, a pastar!

Comment: Creo que te estás pasando con Candid sebas, el no tiene malas intenciones. Perdón si heche leña al fuego, pero me enoja esa mentalidad de las comunidades de se, ya me choqué con eso.

Comment: @CandidMoe si la moderación funcionase correctamente, aceptaría sin problemas esa politica. Pero no si la moderación vota negativo a todo el que responde preguntas de baja calidad pero, el usuario que tiene alta reputación y es querido por muchos recibe positivos. Además, ten en cuenta que el voto negativo resula demasiado facilmente en el bloqueo de la cuenta (diría que permanente, por que no se sabe que hiciste mal como para editar y salir del bloqueo). No te parece justo que reclamemos a los moderadores (la comunidad) la situación?

Comment: Creo que el problema realmente es que esto te genere tanta ansiedad como dices y tanta furia (fíjate que empiezas pidiendo respeto y acabas faltando el respeto a la gente en los comentarios). Todo por un simple voto negativo en internet, que encima iba sin comentario, ni siquiera te habían insultado ni nada parecido... Lo recomendable es sería que pidieras ayuda profesional para este tema ya que en la vida se reciben muchas críticas (justas e injustas) y es una habilidad básica saber encajarlas, habilidad más importante que saber python.

Comment: @ordago Acabo faltando al respeto porque me faltan al respeto. Donde las dan las toman. Y sí, con tanta agresividad ya sé desde hace rato que esto es una batalla perdida. Sencillamente borraré todas mis cuentas de StackExchange. Ya estoy harto de las mismas mierdas año tras año...

Comment: Yo lo que no veo es que sea toxico. Si es un voto negativo, pero un voto negativo no significa nada, y todos recibimos uno siempre...

Comment: Concuerdo con que no es que el sitio sea toxico, y que se está pasando el OP. Pero lo comprendo. Yo he estado en su lugar. Un voto negativo si importa, por dos motivos: el bloqueo y el esfuerzo real por responder. Lo que si, ya saben que opino de la moderación y que incluso considero toxico un dislike sin critica constructiva.

Comment: Esto va más allá del voto negativo. La verdad es que ya me he hartado de la hostilidad de la comunidad StackExchange. Y personas como "CandidMoe" me sacan de quicio con su condescendencia. Estoy harto. Ya no quiero hablar más de este tema.

Comment: @SebasSBM te he dado los votos negativos que considere que son correctos y te he comentado de igual forma los motivos. espero que esto satisfaga tu necesidad de un feedback y comparto la opinion en que todo voto negativo debe tenerlo.

Comment: si tienes alguna duda de como funciona el sitio/ o la comunidad puedes entrar al chat en donde alguien podria responderte: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Gracias, pero ya me hago una idea (si funciona como el StackOverflow original). Y si no, puedo recurrir al [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), como siempre.

Comment: Las puedes borrar tu mismo. Editas tu perfil y te aparece la opción de eliminar la cuenta.

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga Como ya dije, esto va más alla de un voto negativo: se debe a la mecánica presente en StackExchange (y particularmente en StackOverflow) por años. Esta última pregunta que hice tan sólo es un ejemplo más. Moderadores (mejor dicho, usuarios con privilegios de moderador) pueden acusar falsamente a un OP de no haber desarrollado un "Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible" cuando **sí se hizo**, recibir una cascada de votos negativos y a nadie le importa, porque "está curando el sitio" según ellos!! (más información en el enlace que ya posteé en otro comentario)...

Comment: @CandidMoe Tengo demasiadas cuentas de StackExchange. Y las quiero borrar todas. No pienso ir a hacerlo una por una. El RGPD estipula que tengo derecho a borrar todas mis cuentas. Por qué las BigTechs se empeñan en poner trabas para que lo haga? Siguiendo [esta respuesta de MegaStackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291577/292393), la mejor opción es que me lo borren todo ellos mismpos de golpe. Y estoy pendiente de que respondan a mi correo.

Comment: Cinco cuentas no son "demasiadas cuentas". Probablemente sea más rápido borrarlas que escribir un mail pidiéndolo. Me suena a excusa.

Comment: @CandidMoe No me fío ni un pelo. He visto desde dentro cómo las empresas marean de todas las formas posibles a sus usuarios para que no se den de baja. ¿Cómo sé yo que no va a quedar el "perfil maestro" de StackExchange al aire? Tantas facilidades que da para vincular tu cuenta de StackExchange con otras, también debería darlas para borrarlas... así que seguiré esperando su respuesta.

Comment: Yo tenía otras cuentas antes, las que elimine. Las preguntas/respuestas quedaron, pero asignadas a un número. Si eliminas las cuentas, desapareceran.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146773/discussion-between-sebassbm-and-candid-moe).

Comment: Fui a mirar la referencia a Meta en Inglés que nombraste. La primera respuesta comienza con esta frase "SO is evidently unwelcoming, as I can easily demonstrate with explicit evidence. Unfortunately, it seems that the worst abuse is directed at the user-moderators who volunteer to curate the site:". Dice "el peor abuso lo sufren los voluntarios que mantienen el sitio"

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Ya lo he superado. No obstante, considero que el tema de la pregunta sigue siendo relevante.

Answer (score 7):

Ciertamente existe un tema con los votos en el sitio

No obstante, debo ser honesto contigo, a mi me parece que tu pregunta es una mala pregunta y si es merecedora de un voto negativo

Si haces un "hover" al downvote te saldrán 3 razones posibles:

1. No tiene trabajo de investigación
2. **Es confusa**
3. Poco útil

La tuya tiene problemas con el segundo punto.

- Es demasiado larga
- Para entenderla debo ir a leer una fuente externa que:

  - Es aún más larga
  - Esta en otro idioma
- Haces múltiples preguntas, tanto en el texto explicativo como en el código

Además en este momento tiene un voto de cierre por *Necesita ser más específica*, motivo que también me parece que razonablemente aplica a tu pregunta.

---

Para responder tu pregunta de esta publicación:

> Este sitio tiene un nivel de toxicidad comparable al del StackOverflow
> original. ¿Qué podemos hacer al respecto?

No se puede hacer nada, propuestas sobres los votos negativos han habido muchas, desde que los eliminen completamente hasta que sea obligación dar un motivo, así mismo también han existido propuestas para mejorar la convivencia y ser más acogedores. Es que ni siquiera existe consenso en la comunidad de que existan dichos problemas.

Y si comparamos con el tema del ChatGPT donde si existen un consenso mayoritario sobre el no uso y la empresa aun así decide ir en otro sentido...pues tengo cero expectativas que hagan algo con respecto a lo otro.

y es que además ¿Qué se puede hacer? Si la interacción en internet siempre ha sido de esta manera. Personas que dicen cosas amparados en el anonimato, cosas que jamás se atreverían a decir cara a cara

Además, cuanto llevas un tiempo participando te das cuentas que ni el puntaje ni los votos quieren decir algo. Básicamente representan absolutamente nada.

Comment: "Es que ni siquiera existe consenso en la comunidad de que existan dichos problemas." Que lastima que sean tan ciegos, y cuando se los dices, nadie argumenta nada. Por ejemplo, en mi ultima publicación, hubo más de si yo hice bien o mal que si los votos positivos a la respuesta son correctos. Hay que ser ciego para no ver lo obvio (o no se defienden). "ni los votos quieren decir algo" para ellos no querrán decir nada, pero en realidad, significan expulsión. Y si, no hay nada que hacer más que reclamar a los moderadores.

Comment: Si fuera como un simple dislike, que no te bloquea la cuenta, no me preocuparía tanto el voto negativo.

Comment: Exacto, y así muchos otros no les importaría el voto negativo y el sitio no sería lo que es, sino una red antisocial cualquiera de las que ya existen. Entonces, por suerte el sistema está diseñado de la forma en la que está diseñado.

Comment: Entonces, denle buen uso

Comment: Y precisamente por lo respondido (en cierto modo ya imaginaba que ésta sería la respuesta) ya no quiero formar parte de esta comunidad. Gracias por vuestra paciencia.

Comment: @DanteS. Cuando dije  "ni los votos quieren decir algo"  me refiero a que tu puedes ser una eminencia en el rubro, un genio de la programación que nace cada 100 años y haber dado la mejor respuesta a la pregunta más difícil de todos los tiempos, y luego llega un crio que recién hace su primer "hola mundo" y te da un negativo ¿que merito tiene ese voto?

Comment: Por otro lado en el sitio en ingles hay caso de usuarios que tienen +10K con solo haber hecho una pregunta básica hace varios años. Entonces cuando entiendes como funciona la "gamificación" del sitio, te das cuenta que ni el puntaje ni el voto representan algo significativamente importante

Comment: @SebasSBM Tanto yo como los que te han comentado representamos una parte ínfima de la comunidad.  Existe una mayoría silenciosa que es acogedora y agradecida de los aportes que uno puede brindarle

Comment: @Yussef no obstante, esa mayoría es invisible, y seguramente seguiré siéndolo para ellos. Aún quedan algunos que entienden lo que digo, pero parecen minoría en comparación con todos aquellos que se tiran a funarme como hienas por atreverme a cuestionar lo establecido. Y ya estoy muy harto. Se aferran tanto a las normas, que simplemente actúan como autómatas. Se olvidan de todos los principios de "ser agradable con la gente" (que también están en las normas, por cierto). **Es una causa perdida.** Ya no quiero formar parte de esta comunidad.

Comment: @SebasSBM No debes confundir el discrepar contigo con un ataque personal. Yo leí 3 veces tu pregunta y no la entendí, y no la respondería (y mira que yo respondo de todo). También entiendo porque no te dejaron un comentario, a mi una vez me pidieron que justificara un voto, le di mis razones al usuario y finalmente terminó en pelea. Tampoco creo que la comunidad entera te haya funado, tu pregunta actualmente tiene +3/-3, es decir en puntaje neto has ganado reputación por ella

Comment: @SebasSBM Pero fíjate como tu estas haciendo refiriéndote a otro usuario. Para que mejore la comunidad, lo primero es comenzar por uno mismo

Comment: @Yussef Se lo merece.

Comment: Ya lo dijo la mejor respuesta vigente. Los puntos de reputación no son nada más que un mecanismo de otorgación de privilegios. No representan mis habilidades; sólo representan actividad. Nada más. Nada que no supiera ya desde hace años, aunque bien señalado

Comment: @Yussef, te faltaría agregar que existe un sistema de control para los ["Votadores seriales"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) que funciona tanto como para los votos positivos como los negativos. Te dejo [este ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnV4w.png) y [este otro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyPen.png) en carne propia.